# Applying square root to equation

Tags: expression-manipulation

I want to apply square root operation to an equation.

```
In[1]:= Equation := x^2 == 2 y;

In[2]:= Sqrt[Equation]
```

Here is the output:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz97V]

My goal is to simplify this expression, so as it would take `Root` of the left and right parts separately

How can I do that?

Comment: Please copy the code not the image. Have you tried something?

Comment: The image represents the output, not the code itself. Yes. I tried using Simplify function, but with no result.

Comment: We need code to simplify the expression. You have to provide the code, so that we can work on that.

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: You'd eventually be trying to take the square root of True or False, no?

Comment: @Elias Is this what you want [result](http://imgur.com/sCIROX8)

Comment: @L.K., nope, I didn't want to solve it, but rather simplify the equation for further processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally not a good idea to start your symbol names with an uppercase letter and you should look at the difference between `SetDelayed`, i.e. `:=` and `Set`, i.e. `=`.

That said, one answer to your question is to use `Map` (`/@` below) to apply `Sqrt` to both sides of your equation and add an assumption to `Simplify` to allow it to simplify `Sqrt[x^2]` to `x` which is what I assume you want.

```
eqn = x^2 == 2 y;
Simplify[Sqrt /@ eqn, x > 0]
```

> x == Sqrt[2] Sqrt[y]

If you don't want this then `Solve[eqn, x]`, gives an alternative form as stated by others.

Answer (score 2):

`Thread[]` is one of the classical ways to do this operation:

```
Thread[Sqrt[x^2 == 2 y], Equal]
   Sqrt[x^2] == Sqrt[2] Sqrt[y]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Solve[x^2 == 2 y, {x}]
```

> ```
> {{x -> -Sqrt[2] Sqrt[y]}, {x -> Sqrt[2] Sqrt[y]}}
> ```

Comment: I must have been a time traveler. ;) I answered it 33 minutes ago and Mike answered it 22 minutes ago.

Comment: Right, accept my apologies. :)